# Search engine only single return?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search

Hello everyone i made a simple search engine but there is one problem with it, when i search a string my result is only one line what did i do wrong i can't find it for multiple results.

Search.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['search']) && !empty($_POST['xs']) && isset($_POST['s']))
    echo $functions->Search($_POST['xs'], $_POST['s']);
?>
```

functions.php:

```
    function Search( $post, $type )
    {
    global $database;
        if ($database->getSearchData($type, $post) && preg_replace("/[^0-9A-Za-z]/", "", $post))
        return $database->getSearchData($type, $post);
         else
         return 
         '
<div class="title_box"><div class="title_inner">
Results </div></div>
<div class="title2_box"><div class="title2_inner">
<p>
<table width="50%">
<tr>
<td>Player</td>
<td>Level</td>
<td>Total honour</td>
</tr>
<tr><td class="f" colspan="2">No results</td></tr></table>  </p>
</div></div>
        ';
    }
```

database.php:

```
        function getSearchData($type, $keyword)
        {
        $find = strtoupper( $find );
        $find = strip_tags( $find );
        $find = trim ( $find );

            switch($type)
            {
                case '1':
                    $q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE upper(username) LIKE '%$keyword%'";
                break;
                case '2':
                    //$q = "SELECT * FROM guilds WHERE upper(username) LIKE '%$keyword%' LIMIT 25";
                    return false;
                break;
                case '3':
                    //$q = "SELECT * FROM guilds WHERE upper(username) LIKE '%$keyword%' LIMIT 25";
                    return false;
                break;
                default:
                    return false;
                break;
            }

            $result = mysql_query($q, $this->connection);

            if(mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0)
                return false;

             while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
             { 
    return
    '
<div class="title_box"><div class="title_inner">
Results </div></div>
<div class="title2_box"><div class="title2_inner">
<p>
<table width="50%">
<tr>
<td>Player</td>
<td>Level</td>
<td>Total honour</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<a href="index.php?mod=player&p='.$row['id'].'" " target="_self">'.$row['username'].'</a>
</td>
<td style="text-align:center">'.$row['level'].'</td>
<td style="text-align:center">'.$row['honour'].'</td>
</tr>
</table>    </p>
</div></div>
    ';
             } 
        }
```

Problem only one result need multiple.

Comment: Do not forget to [properly escape your SQL](http://bobby-tables.com/). You're also using `mysql_query`, which is deprecated and dangerous. Unless you have a very good reason for using it, please don't, it's being removed from PHP in the near future. [Use PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) instead if you can.

Comment: You need to learn how to debug code before asking for help. The solution to this is glaringly obvious.

Comment: I know about PDO and about mysql.
Sverri M. Olsen, thanks for advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You called `return` in your `while` loop. When `return` is called, the function exits and sends the specified data back to the caller. This can happen only once per function call.

To correct this problem, you may want to create a temporary variable to store your result set and concatenate onto it each time you iterate over your result set. Then you can call `return` once after the loop ends to return the entire set.